# Does abstract class hide or override the method of the interface?

Tags: java

I am studying for OCA and I try to find answer for every question I encounter in my head.

This is the code:

```
interface InterfaceA {
public default Number method(){
    return 5;
}

}

abstract class AbstractB {
    public Long method() {
        return 3L;
    }
}

public class Foo extends AbstractB implements InterfaceA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Foo().method());
    }
}
    }
```

In this situation I don't have to override in the class `Foo`.
I know if I implement 2 interfaces with same methods I have to explicitly override in the class `Foo`. In the example above I get the result from `AbstractB` (3). My question: is abstract class implicitly overriding or hiding the method from the interface? What is the reason that class `Foo` prints the result from `AbstractB` and not from `InterfaceA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract classes *implement* methods from interfaces. This does not count as an override, because there is no base method to override. In other words, if you try to do this

```
abstract class AbstractB {
    public Long method() {
        return super.method(); // <<==== Does not compile!
    }
}
```

the call to base class `method()` would not compile.

Hiding does not apply either, because only `static` methods in Java can be hidden.

> why class `Foo` gets the result from his parent class and not from interface?

Because interface provides a default implementation, i.e. what you get when there's nothing else provided in the line of inheritance. In this case, abstract base class provides an implementation, so it "wins" over the default implementation from the interface.

Comment: I understand now why it's not overriding or hiding but why class Foo gets the result from his parent class and not from interface?

Answer (score 0):

in this specific case the call to `println` prints `3` because `AbstractB` implements the method `method` of the interface `InterfaceA` in which case the class `Foo` inherits this bevahior. However, had `AbstractB` not implemented the interface method the `println` call would delegate to the default method of `InterfaceA`. Lastly, to answer your question `AbstractB` *does not* hide the method of the interface rather *implements it* as it has the same signature as the method in `InterfaceA`.